# How to loop with a filter?

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery

I would basically like a loop where after generating the table with the filter of 202108 (my variable), it goes back to the beginning and runs 202109, 202110, 202111 and so on.

```sql
DECLARE MONTHYEAR INT64 DEFAULT 202208;

 select distinct 
    count(distinct a.cus_cust_id)
  FROM tabela_a 
  where 1=1
      and MONTHYEAR = MONTHYEAR
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you do not need for loops in almost cases. If you want to count `cus_cust_id` by `monthyear` you can use a `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT
 monthyear,
 COUNT(DISTINCT a.cus_cust_id)
FROM tabela_a
GROUP BY monthyear
```